Using DevExpress XtraReport Constructor with parameter
I am creating reports with .NET Core Web API. I am using object data source as data source in my reports. I need to access domain services to get the data for these reports. I use DI with Autofac in the project. How can I do this with Devexpress?

I would like to share the solution I have found for those who have the same problem as me.
public class CustomWebDocumentViewerReportResolver : IWebDocumentViewerReportResolver
 {
     private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

     public CustomWebDocumentViewerReportResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
     {
         _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
     }

     public XtraReport Resolve(string reportEntry)
     {
         switch (reportEntry)
         {
             case "Report1":
                 return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Report1>(_serviceProvider);
             default:
                 Type t = Type.GetType(reportEntry);
                 return typeof(XtraReport).IsAssignableFrom(t) ?
                     (XtraReport)Activator.CreateInstance(t) :
                     null;
         }
     }
 }

private readonly ITest1 _test1;
private readonly ITest2 _test2;

public Report1(ITest1 test1, ITest2 test2)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _test1 = test1;
    _test2 = test2;
}

